# woocommerce add_fee через значение поля на странице заказа

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

В общем есть поле dostavka в него скриптом записывается значение (оно произвольное) и мне нужно добавить его к заказу мой код работает на странице оформления заказа, но не записывается в сам заказ и на страницу с детальной информацией по заказу

```
add_action('woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'add_ship_fee');

function add_ship_fee() {
    global $woocommerce;

    if (!empty($_POST['post_data'])) {
        parse_str($_POST['post_data'], $postdata);
    }
    if (!empty($postdata['dostavka'])) {
        $fee = (int) $postdata['dostavka'];
    }
    $woocommerce->cart->add_fee('Доставка:', $fee, false);
}
```

Интересно что если заменить последнюю строчку на:

```
$woocommerce->cart->add_fee('Доставка:', 150, false);
```

То стоимость добавляется так как должна, не могу понять где ошибка
[image: Работающая доставка]

Comment: НУ значит у тебя в $fee ничего нет

Comment: Нахрена тут parse_str? Она для строк такого вида `$str = "first=value&arr[]=foo+bar&arr[]=baz";
`. У вас точно не такая строка.в `$_POST[ 'post_data' ].

Comment: Поставьте уже простейший var_dump и посмотрите, что у вас там.

Comment: Я прекрасно знаю для чего нужен parse_str в post data "..&dostavka=710&order_comments=&shipping_method%5B0%5D=cdek.."

Comment: Вопрос не в том что в $fee ничего нет, это то я понимаю, вопрос в том почему если поставить 150 то работает везде, а если $fee то только на оформлении заказа? Функция как я понимаю вызывается один раз, и должна 1 раз подставить значение $fee и добавить наценку к заказу

Answer (score 0, accepted):

проблема решена вот таким образом

```
add_action('woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', function() {
    global $woocommerce;
    $postdata = [];
    if (!empty($_POST['post_data'])) {
        $fields = parse_str($_POST['post_data'], $postdata);
    }
    $fee = empty($postdata['dostavka']) ? 0 : (int) $postdata['dostavka'];
    if (!$fee) {
        $fee = empty($_POST['dostavka']) ? 0 : (int) $_POST['dostavka'];
    }
    if ($fee) {
        $woocommerce->cart->add_fee('Доставка СДЭК:', $fee, false);
    }
});
```